# SQL Server Pivot Table Help

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot

I'm trying to turn the following ResultSet

```
Meetings Covers   Date         TypeName
1         3       2010-10-14   Breakfast
1         1       2010-10-14   LunchCooked
2         4       2010-10-15   Breakfast
1         3       2010-10-18   Breakfast
1         3       2010-10-19   Breakfast
1         1       2010-10-19   LunchSandwich
1         3       2010-10-20   Breakfast
1         3       2010-10-21   Breakfast
1         3       2010-10-22   Breakfast
```

Into a format with the following fields

```
Date
BreakfastMeetings
BreakfastCovers
LunchSandwichMeetings
LunchSandwichCovers
LunchCookedMeetings
LunchCookedCovers
```

Am I right in thinking this can be done with pivot tables? Any pointers would be great otherwise I'm going to end up taking some sort of hacky temp table route to get the data into this format.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it.  It actually needs and unpivot and a pivot operation.  The unpivot combines the Meetings and Covers into a single column and changes the TypeName values to the desired column names.

The pivot uses the results of the unpivot to provide the final format.

```
SELECT TheDate, BreakfastMeetings, BreakfastCovers, LunchSandwichMeetings,
    LunchSandwichCovers, LunchCookedMeetings, LunchCookedCovers
FROM (
    -- unpivot to put counts in single column and create new type names
    SELECT TheDate, TypeName + MeetingCover AS TypeName, RowCounts
    FROM (SELECT TheDate, TypeName, Meetings, Covers
        FROM MyTable
        ) AS p
        UNPIVOT (RowCounts FOR MeetingCover IN (Meetings, Covers)
        ) AS UnpivotTable
    ) AS Source
    -- pivot the unpivoted data to create new columns
    PIVOT ( MAX(RowCounts) FOR TypeName IN (BreakfastMeetings, BreakfastCovers,
                                            LunchSandwichMeetings,
                                            LunchSandwichCovers,
                                            LunchCookedMeetings,
                                            LunchCookedCovers)
) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY TheDate
```

Comment: Just what I needed thanks. Really wish I could get my head around the whole Pivot thing but there is something about it that I really struggle to grasp